# Add a column into table after the table is created

Tags: sql

I have already created a table named `starsin`. Now I want to add a column `address` in my table `starsin` by using a query. How can I do this?

Comment: You should really specify what server you are using, then you will get better answers.

Comment: Maybe Abid is smarter than most and wants SQL that's vendor-agnostic so as to not be locked in to any one DBMS :-)

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you want the `alter table X add column Y ...` command.

If you then want to populate the column for all existing rows, it's a simple matter of working out the query and: `update X set Y = ...`.

---

Here's an example session which shows you the `alter table add column` in action (for DB2):

```
> CREATE TABLE XYZ (F1 INTEGER);                       
DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 0  

> INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES (1);                          
DSNE615I NUMBER OF ROWS AFFECTED IS 1                      
DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 0  

> INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES (2);                          
DSNE615I NUMBER OF ROWS AFFECTED IS 1                      
DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 0  

> SELECT * FROM XYZ;                                   
F1                                                
--
 1                                                
 2                                                
DSNE610I NUMBER OF ROWS DISPLAYED IS 2                     
DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 100

> ALTER TABLE XYZ ADD COLUMN F2 INTEGER;               
DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 0  

> UPDATE XYZ SET F2 = F1 + 7;                          
DSNE615I NUMBER OF ROWS AFFECTED IS 2                      
DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 0  

> SELECT * FROM XYZ;                                   
F1   F2                                   
--   --
 1    8                                   
 2    9                                   
DSNE610I NUMBER OF ROWS DISPLAYED IS 2                     
DSNE616I STATEMENT EXECUTION WAS SUCCESSFUL, SQLCODE IS 100
```

Comment: do i have to drop a table afrer altering it?

Comment: ...not unless you want to get rid of it

Comment: Good one, Matti :-) No, altering doesn't create a new table, it modifies the current table.

Answer (score 0):

If this is mysql, you can do `ALTER TABLE stasin ADD COLUMN <columnname> <type> <options>`

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7120.asp)

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE Sales 
ADD UnitPrice MONEY;
```

Output:
The command(s) completed successfully.
Explanation:
This example adds a single field to the 'Sales' table by specifying the new field name and data type.
Language(s): MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ADD(<coloumn name> <datatype>);
```

Normal SQL query to add a coloumn. In oracle, it will work.